# In Java can you condense multiple dialog boxes into just one

Tags: java, loops, dialog

is there a way to turn multiple dialog boxes into just one?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class loop {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int input;
    int sum = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    String num = "";


    input=(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter an integer")));


    if (input == (-input)) {

        input = input * (-1);
        num = String.valueOf(input);
        num1 = num.length();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"the digits of " + input + " are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
            String var = num.substring(i, counter);
            int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, var + " ");
            sum = sum + var1;
            counter++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"the sum is: " + sum);

    } else {
        num = String.valueOf(input);
        num1 = num.length();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the digits of " + input + " are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
            String var = num.substring(i, counter);
            int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,var + " ");
            sum = sum + var1;
            counter++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
}
```

I have to write a program that has the user input an integer and the program will output the number broken down and the sum. With the code above I can run that program but each number of the broken down integer has its own dialog box, is it possible to have it output a single dialog box instead of the multiple?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

 public class loop{
 public static void main(String []args){


  {

  long a,b,test;
  long counter = 0;


     a=(Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter an integer")));
     test = a;
     while (test > 0)

     {
     test  = test/10;
     counter = counter + 1;
     }
     counter = counter - 1;


     while (counter >= 0)
     {  
     b = a% (long) Math.pow(10, counter);
     a = a/(long) Math.pow(10,counter);
     a = b;
     counter = counter - 1;

    {
    String longString=String.valueOf(a);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a + " ");
    }
   }
   }
   }
   }
```

I started going a bit of a different way with it but now its condense some of the numbers and outputting a 0 which was never entered.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Don't call `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` in a for-loop.
Assign the values into a String outside the loop, and then after the loop is done, call `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` passing the String instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I'm missing something simple, that or over complicating it. However, I can not get String right at this point. If you have the time could you show me an example please?